# Browser Caching problems

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, browser-cache

I created a shopping cart application but after add items to shopping cart from products page and then go to the cart page cart is showing empty, but after refresh product is showing, I think browser caching pages. So Is there a method to fix this issue, Please help me

Note: I used cakephp framework with MVC

Thanks

Comment: Here's how to avoid and stop caching of your browser permanently! Use both PHP and HTML at the top of each page:

`<?php header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); ?>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">`

Comment: Are you *redirecting* to the products page? Or 'internally' showing the product view? Does your firebug/webinspector show `from cache` in the `network` panel?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the browser from caching the cart page, add a 'no-cache' header;

### Disable browser-caching in CakePHP 1.x

```
public function cart()
{
    $this->disableCache();
    // rest of your code here
}
```

### Disable browser-caching in CakePHP 2.x

In CakePHP 2.x the 'disableCache()' method has been moved to the response-object

```
public function cart()
{
    $this->response->disableCache();
    // rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are making call to your page add some time stamp to the address or url like

get current time in variable  MS(jav mili second time can be used) and change your URL lik myPage.jsp?MS

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can do so by calling

```
Cache::clear()
```

This will clear all cached data, excluding cached view files. If you need to clear the cached view files, use

```
clearCache().
```

Comment: This will clear *server-side* cache, not *browser cache*. Clearing the CakePHP caches for each request is a **bad** idea as it will seriously affect the performance of your website